# Regex lowercase script validation

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, regular-expression

I am working on a homework assignment to validate whether an entered string is in all lowercase letters. Here is the basic script that we are provided.

Here is the line I need to change.

```
if [[ "$input" =~ Add your regular expression here ]]
```

If I put `[a-z]` entering anything with just one instance of a lowercase letter will validate.
With `[[:lower:]]` "Brian" will validate and "cats" will not but gibberish such as `trhrh` is fine. I don't know the regex to use here. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Test whether the string contains anything that is *not* a lower case letter.

```
if [[ "$input" =~ [^[:lower:]] ]]; then
    # contains something that is not a lower case letter
else
    # contain only lower case letters
fi
```

or,

```
if ! [[ "$input" =~ [^[:lower:]] ]]; then
    # contain only lower case letters
fi
```

The `^` at the start of a bracketed expression inverses the sense of the match, so that `[^abc]` matches any single character that is *not* `a`, `b`, or `c`.

Alternatively, match the whole length of the string by anchoring the string at both ends:

```
if [[ "$input" =~ ^[[:lower:]]+$ ]]; then
    # contain only lower case letters
fi
```

The `^` at the start of the expression only anchors to the start of the string while the `$` at the end anchors to the end of the string.  In between these we allow only lower case letter using `[[:lower:]]+`, i.e. one or more lower case letters.  Using `*` in place of `+` would allow the expression to successfully match on an empty string too.

Note also the difference between `[[:lower:]]` (matches a single lower case letter) and `[:lower:]` matches one of the characters `:`, `l`, `o`, `w`, `e`, or `r`). In the original question, you said that `Brian` was matched by `[:lower:]` while `cats` wasn't, which should make sense now. In an edit, you changed the expression to the correct `[[:lower:]]`, and `cats` should now also be matched.

---

With a globbing match in place for the regular expression match:

```
if [[ "$input" == *[![:lower:]]* ]]; then
    # contains something that is not a lower case letter
else
    # contain only lower case letters
fi
```

In a globbing pattern, `!` at the start of a bracketed expression works the same as the `^` in the regular expression case (although I believe `bash` also recognizes `^` there in globbing patterns).

Answer (score 0):

**You can also check with this one Liner if you want :**

```
echo "$input" | grep -qE '^[[:lower:]]*$' && echo "All LowerCase" || echo "Not All LowerCase"
```